# cURL Error 7 When Making POST Request from Laravel 10 on Shared Hosting to Remote Server

Tags: http, curl, guzzle, laravel-10

I'm encountering an issue with making a POST request from a Laravel application hosted on shared hosting to a remote server. The code works fine in my local development environment and Postman, but I encounter a cURL error 7 when deployed to the shared hosting environment.

```
Objective: I have a Laravel application running on shared hosting. It's supposed to make a POST request to a remote server at http://**.**.***.***:5000.

Environment Details:
    Laravel version: Laravel 10
    Shared hosting provider: htp:://subdomain.domain.com

Controller Code: Here is the relevant code from my Laravel controller:
```

```
public function send(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request data (you can add more validation rules as needed)
    $this->validate($request, [
        'message_session' => 'required',
        'whatsapp_user_id' => 'required',
        'sender_id' => 'required',
        'messageTime' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        // Start a database transaction
        DB::beginTransaction();
        
        // Create a new WhatsappMessages instance and populate it with the request data
        $whatsappMessage = new WhatsappMessages();
        $whatsappMessage->message_session = $request->input('message_session');
        $whatsappMessage->whatsapp_user_id = $request->input('whatsapp_user_id');
        $whatsappMessage->sender_id = $request->input('sender_id');
        $whatsappMessage->messageTime = $request->input('messageTime');
        $whatsappMessage->messageText = $request->input('message');

        if (auth()->user()->id == $request->input('sender_id')) {
            // Define the URL of the endpoint
            $url = env('MESSAGE_API_URL') . '/send-message';
            
            // Prepare the data to send in the request
            $data = [
                'to' => $request->input('phone'),
                'message' => $request->input('message'),
            ];

            // Make a POST request to the endpoint
            $response = Http::post($url, $data);
            // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
            if ($response['status']==200) {
                // Save the instance to the database
                $whatsappMessage->save();

                // Commit the database transaction
                DB::commit();

                // Return a JSON response indicating that the message was sent
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Message sent successfully']);
            } else {
                // The request to the external service was not successful
                // Roll back the database transaction
                DB::rollBack();

                // Return a JSON response indicating the failure to send the message
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to send message to WhatsApp'], 500);
            }
        } else {
            // Save the instance to the database
            $whatsappMessage->save();

            // Commit the database transaction
            DB::commit();

            // Return a JSON response indicating that the message was received
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Message received successfully']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // An exception occurred
        // Roll back the database transaction
        DB::rollBack();

        // Log the exception for debugging
        Log::error($e);

        // Return a JSON response indicating an error
        return response()->json(['message' => 'An error occurred while processing the request'], 500);
    }
}
```

Issue Details: The problem arises when I include the following line in my controller code:

$response = Http::post($url, $data);

Without this line, the code runs perfectly on the shared hosting environment.

Error Message: When I include the line mentioned above, I get the following cURL error:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to **.**.***.*** port 5000 after 1003 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://**.**.***.***:5000/send-message
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

```
Ensuring that the server configuration at http://**.**.***.***:5000 is correctly set up and accessible from external sources like postman or from my localhost using the controller code. Yes This code also working in my localhost and make the post request. Postman also worked. Just doesn't work when it is in the shared hosting.
```

Request for Assistance:

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to resolve the issue. I suspect it might be related to the shared hosting environment's configuration or restrictions. If anyone has experience with similar cURL connectivity issues on shared hosting or can provide guidance on how to troubleshoot further, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Result Of Postman]
[image: Header Of Postman]

Answer (score 0):

if centos - redhat apache,

```bash
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-booleans#:~:text=httpd_can_network_connect,Boolean%20to%20allow%20this%20access](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-booleans#:%7E:text=httpd_can_network_connect,Boolean%20to%20allow%20this%20access).